# Python Flask SSL Timed Out, Non-SSL is fine

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I'm seemingly have problem trying to deploy my Flask app with SSL.

The non-SSL works fine at:

http://transcribe.22ai.net:5000/

But fails to provide a secure connection at

https://transcribe.22ai.net:5000/

Here is my simple code, certificate is from Let's Encrypt:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import ssl

app = Flask(__name__)

context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.load_cert_chain('fullchain.pem', 'privkey.pem')

'''
Flask Routes
'''
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])

def index():

    return "hello"

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(ssl_context=context)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

There is no errors, below is output:

```
2021-06-13 06:54:15 +0000] [27045] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (27045)
[2021-06-13 06:54:15 +0000] [27045] [INFO] Using worker: geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker
[2021-06-13 06:54:15 +0000] [27053] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27053
[2021-06-13 06:54:15 +0000] [27054] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27054
[2021-06-13 06:54:15 +0000] [27057] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In your output it clearly says that it is listening at `http://...` and not `https://...`, which would explain why `https://` requests will not work. With  exactly your code it shows me that it it is listening on `https://` though - and accessing with `https://` then also works for me. My guess is that what you show as simplified code does not reflect what you are running in practice, which also means that what you show is useless to debug the problem you actually have.

Comment: Hey Steffan, thanks for response. You are right, and somehow I can't get gunicorn to recognize it as an SSL. I have managed to find a temporary fix - running as python as opposed to Flask.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated command line run as suggested by Steffen.

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app --certfile fullchain.pem --keyfile privkey.pem —-error-logfile ./logs/error.log --capture-output --log-level debug
```

Comment: `flask run` loads the app as a module and thus does not execute `if __name__=='__main__': ....`. Instead flask uses its own handler here, which can also be augmented using the `--cert` etc arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Set the port to 443

```
app.run(ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'), port=443)
```